# OAuth Consent Screen Showing Amplify URL instead of App Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a simple amplify app that is using google as an authenticator and SSO service. I have updated the consent screen to display the app name but it continues to show the amazon cognito url instead of the app name. The app has been moved from testing to published but the issue is persistent. How do I make this change?